# Given a number, create a set of 2-tuples whose sum is equal to the provided number starting from (1, 1)

Tags: python

It gave me an example but how can I compute it?

```
enter code here
create_dice_sets(6) --> ([(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)])
create_dice_sets(2) --> [(1, 1)]
create_dice_sets(1) --> [()]
```

this is what i have given.

```
enter code here
def create_dice_sets(number):
    #Fill your code here.
    return result

print(create_dice_sets(6))
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Try it and come back when you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the range of values between 1 and the given number and create a tuple with the value `i` and `number - i` at every turn:

*I think this is a homework so I assume you are not allowed to use any built-in function to do this.*

```
>>> def create_dice_sets(number):
...     result = []
...     for i in range(1, number):
...         result.append((i, number - i))
...     return result
```

*Btw, there is bug in the code for the given number being equal to 1.*

Demo:

```
>>> create_dice_sets(6)
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]

>>> create_dice_sets(2)
[(1, 1)]

>>> create_dice_sets(1)
[]
```